# 1 bit audio player

Tags: customization

I have wordpress and I use [1 bit audio player (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/1-bit-audio-player/) to add songs. When I try to download a song, it shows in the URL but it is not inserted in the description.

Comment: Could you please provide more details what exactly isn't working as it should? Some code you use (and maybe a screenshot if it makes sense) would help to understand your question better.

Answer (score 2):

The [1 bit audio player (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/1-bit-audio-player/) hasn't been updated for a long time and according to it's own information, it is compatible up to [Wordpress 2.5 (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.5) only.

I assume that it's just not working with your Wordpress version, so you need to find a working plugin first.